# Where to put a interface related variable that it is not static and final

Tags: java, interface

I am in a very early stage of game development. It is some sort of turn based game like Warhammer or Warcraft. Some creatures can regenerate the damage they have suffered and to represent this I have a interface like this

```
public interface Regenerative {
    void regenerates();
}
```

So a creature that regenerates is

```
public class SomeMonster() extends BaseCreature implements Regeneative{
 //Code
 private int hitPoints;

 public void regenerates(){
  hitPoints = hitPoints + regenerateValue;
 }
}
```

The problem I face is that not all the creatures regenerates the same ammount of hit points so I have to place that amount (regenerateValue) somewhere. Since I cannot put it on the interface (because I don't want the ammount to be the same to all the creatures) I have thought in adding a new property to the creature class

```
public class SomeMonster() extends BaseCreature implements Regeneative{
 //Code
 private int regenerateValue;

 public void regenerates(){
  hitPoints = hitPoints + regenerateValue;
 }
}
```

but I don't like it this way (why a creature that doesn't regenerate should have a regenerateValue of 0?). I think it is giving a class unnecesary properties and thus a bad design. What do you think is the best approach for this case?

Comment: you can still overload the method in an upper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i use may be a bit over-ingeniered, but this allow for a lot of extension (regeneration, poison, protection...)

I use of interface "CreatureProperties" that define a integer value along with an id, and can perform action on a monster at each turn. You subclass those properties to perform a given property

```
abstract class CreatureProperties {
   protected String id = "";
   protectd int propertyValue = 0;
   public void actOn(BaseMonster);
  // plus setter and getter
}

public RegenerationProperty implements CreatureProperties {
   final public REGENERATION_ID = "Regeneration";
   int regenerationValue = 0;

   public RegenerationProperty(int value){
      id = REGENERATION_ID;
      propertyValue= value;
   }

   public void actOn(BaseMonster monster){
      monster.setHitPoint(monster.getHitPoints()+propertyValue);
   }
}

in the BaseMonster class, you manage a set of MonsterProperty, initially empty.

    class BaseMonster {
       protected List<CreatureProperties> properties = 
         new ArrayList<CreatureProperties>();
       // plus management of propeties : add remove, iterator...

       public void update(){
          // perform all properties-linked update to monster
          foreach (CreatureProperty property : properties){
             property.actOn(this);
          }
       } 
    }
```

in the subclass for SomeMonster, you simply add during instanciation the set of properties for this type of monster.

```
class SomeMonster extends BaseMonster {
   public SomeMonster(){
      properties.add(new RegenerationProperty(5));  // presto : monster regenerate
   }
}
```

I'm using the Id in some case where the property is not used each tick (ie nothing in the update), but for example damage reduction (id="LightningReduction"), or to modify the list of existing properties (a property that remove all regenerationProperty and add  PoisonProperty of same value...).

Comment: you can also extend the solution with a duration in that is diminued each update for each Properties, and removed from the list when equal to zero, thus allowing temporary properties... this is how i set spell effects (oups "nanite boost" in my game) on monster.

Comment: Yes. I actually added some properties to the abstract class to represent duration and so. ;) It's a great solution. BTW What is your game?

Comment: well its not really well defined. It started as a simily "settler" game with robots, but evolved with my interest. i'm currently playing with the map generator and the property generator. the latest are linked to "chromosome" wich mean that you can cross-breed robot and get something with more or less power, depending on the genotypeof the crossed units. I'm not even sure its fun for anyone other than me.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem I face is that not all the creatures regenerates the same ammount of hit points so I have to place that amount (regenerateValue) somewhere.

Why does it have to be a *field* anywhere? Some implementations of the interface might use a different value per instance; others might use a constant value.

This is an *implementation detail* - and thus inappropriate for the interface. You *could* potentially put it in an abstract superclass which implements the interface, of course.

Code which knows about the interface almost certainly shouldn't know or care the details of how much a creature regenerates - maybe they regenerate in terms of magic rather than just hit points, for example, or maybe the level of regeneration depends on some other function of their state. Callers shouldn't care.

Answer (score 2):

I would add it to the `abstract` BaseCreature and not worry about it too much. Your BaseCreature may end up with lots of properties which are effectively "turned off" but the alternative is to create a complex inheritance tree. As Java doesn't support multiple inheritance this will frustrate your ability to abstract all the combinations you might like away.

Answer (score 1):

What if all monster regenerate, but some of them with 0 regenerate value (the same as not regenerating)?

So you don't need the inferface:

```
public class SomeMonster() extends BaseCreature {
 //Code
    protected int regenerateValue; //protected, so that subclasses can override the value

    public void regenerates(){
        hitPoints = hitPoints + regenerateValue;
    }
}
```

The regenerateValue starts with 0, so you have to override the value in subclasses that want to actually regenerate

Edited to remove the " implements Regeneative"

Answer (score 1):

I think your design is probably ok, as you would only need to include a regenerateValue in the classes that implement the Regenerative interface.  So there would be no need to include a regenerateValue.

Otherwise you could look at more complex design patterns that favor composition over inheritance.  This way you could cater for the possibility of dynamically adding Regenerative abilities to a monster along with other 'abilities' during the game, rather than having to recompile the game each time you need to make change the behaviour of your monster.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method in your interface, like getRegnerationValue(), making sure all creatures with that interface have this method that holds the value or formula if that is something you would like to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The question you should ask yourself is this:  if a creature should regenerate, how do you know that?  Will it implement a different (or extending) base class?  one that implements Regenerative?

If the answer is that you will extend the base class (to something like BaseRegeneratingCreature) and all regenerating creatures will extend that class, then this is your answer: BaseRegeneratingCreature should implement that interface, and have all properties required for regenerating.

All non-regenerating creatures should directly extend BaseCreature (or another extending class), and will not need the regeneration related properties.

Then, your base class could have some method like:

```
OnStartOfTurn();
```

which will, in BaseRegeneratingCreature, call regenerates() (and then probably call super()), and in BaseCreature do something else or call other methods.